# Add slashes to .php file extensions only

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

my htaccess codes add a slash to the end of all URLs but I just want it to add slashes to files ending with the .php file extension how can I do that?

my htaccess codes :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(.*?)\/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. Written with shown samples only. Please make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/seo$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I will open another thread for this problem. You already answered the question I asked.